# Does this higher-order polynomial have an analytic solution?

Tags: polynomials

I know that in general polynomials above degree 4 do not have analytic solutions, except for a few special cases.  What I want to know is whether this particular polynomial is one of those cases.  The equation is

$$ax^p+bx^q+c=0$$

where p and q are both positive integers.  One of them equals 4, if that helps at all.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in terms of hypergeometric functions in one variable. To quote,

"... This technique gives closed-form solutions in terms of hypergeometric functions in one variable for any polynomial equation which can be written in the form $x^p+bx^q+c = 0$..."

See (eq.42) of this [Mathworld entry](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuinticEquation.html).

P.S. If in radicals, and $x^p+bx^q+c = 0$ is irreducible (and I assume $p,q$ are co-prime), "...Guralnick and Shareshian proved that if the degree of the equation is $d\ge7$ (except $d=8$), then there are only finitely many equivalence classes of irreducible degree $d$ trinomials in $\bf{Q}[x]$ whose Galois group is solvable...". See [the answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146769/is-there-an-irreducible-but-solvable-septic-trinomial-x7axnb-0) to my MathOverflow question about septic trinomials $x^7+ax+b=0$.