# On solvable equations and a good book about Galois Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, radicals, book-recommendation, solvable-groups

Well, as the title says I would like to know a good and **direct** book about Galois Theory **(and also that apllies the theory for the study of polynomials)**. It's been kinda impossible for me to find such one, since I have tried a few books (non-intuitive and non-direct, one of them was a Thomas Hungerford's) on this theory.

About the other question: I know that there are no solutions in radicals of higher than 4 degree polynomial equations, however, I have seen these questions: [Trigonometric solution to solvable equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1826319/trigonometric-solution-to-solvable-equations?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Does this higher-order polynomial have an analytic solution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566187/does-this-higher-order-polynomial-have-an-analytic-solution/566195#566195). So, my question is:

And what about the **unsolvable** ones? We can only find the roots through numerical methods? Also, which books about this would you recommend me reading?

Comment: It is easy to find an approximation of the roots of a complex polynomial (for any initial point, the gradient descent, minimizing $|f(z)|^2$, converges to a root, once you have found an approximation $b$ of a root $a$ you can approximate $f(z)/(z-a) \approx (f(z)-f(b))/(z-b)=g(z)$ and repeat the gradient descent with $g$). The radical/solvable stuffs are about polynomials with closed-form factorization in term of elementary functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning Galois theory, I suggest Jean-Pierre Tignol's *Galois' Theory of Algebraic Equations*.

And concerning the solution of higher degree equations, I suggest Jerry Shurman's *Geometry of the Quintic*.

Comment: Thanks sir, I'm on my way to getting these.